# Custom training loops for LSTMs (Tensorflow 2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am currently implementing the neural image captioning model shown here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning

The training loop passes a batch of sentences word by word into the decoder. While implementing the model, I noticed that the hidden state of the previous timestep is not fed into the GRU. To make sure to that the GRU does not store the hidden state of the previous timestep, I wrote my own toy example and found that it indeed does not store the hidden state:

```
    input_word = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,5))
    h = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
    c = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
    out, new_h, new_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(3, return_state=True, name='lstm')(input_word) #h and c not passed into LSTM
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(out)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_word, h, c], outputs=[out, new_h, new_c])

    sequence = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 3, 5]), dtype=tf.float32)
    c = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]), dtype=tf.float32)
    h = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]), dtype=tf.float32)
    current_input = tf.expand_dims(sequence[:, 0], 1)
    for i in range(1, sequence.shape[1]):
        print(model.get_layer('lstm').states)
        predictions, h, c = model([current_input[: i], h, c])
        print(model.get_layer('lstm').states)
        current_input = tf.expand_dims(sequence[:, i], 1)
```

The print states statements return `[None, None]` .

I am positive that this is a lack of understanding on my part rather than Google making a mistake. However, I would be very grateful if someone can explain to me how the GRU knows what the hidden state of the previous timestep is.

Thank you very much!